# How can I import firefox-ios to my obj-C project

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, mozilla

I wonder how can I import https://github.com/mozilla/firefox-ios to my existing Obj-C project. While it does not a framework, I could not import sources of it in my Obj-C project files when I added the project into workspace. I tried to convert it to a static library, but I could not figured it out. I have a little bit experience on Swift and this creating static library thing. Actually, I am not sure this is the right way to do.

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do, but check this out https://github.com/mozilla/firefox-ios/tree/master/ThirdParty/Alamofire/iOS%20Example.xcodeproj, it might help you. Best of luck.

Comment: what error message you got?

Answer (score 0):

You should check the [Apples documentation about using Swift in Objective-c](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/MixandMatch.html).(The *Importing Swift into Objective-C* part)

You can add a Swift-module header and import your `.swift` files and use them in your objective-c code.